# Concerns regarding exposing ip and open port

Tags: security, ip, java, port

I've written a server. It's written in java and only sorts connections away if they've connected within the last second.

I'm concerned about exposing my IP and which port is open.

What are the dangers of exposing your IP and which ports are open? Does running my server software, which basically only executes readLine() and write() statements, in regard to the connected socket, pose any risk?

If so, are there any solutions I can use or preemptive steps I can take?

I'm a bit confused about this whole topic, reading and hearing so many different things.

Thank you,
Mike.

Answer (score 2):

As is the case with any service listening on an IP:port, you open yourself up to the risk of being exploited.  Some exploits will compromise only the network service in question, others, depending on the vulnerability, and several other factors including the permissions the service has, can compromise the PC, by gaining root access.

For instance, if there is a vulnerability where a buffer overflow causes privileged information to be exposed, or execution of arbitrary code, you can open yourself up for some fun times ;)

When testing, I recommend doing so in controlled environments, limiting the possibility of a malicious person trying to exploit anything you're testing.